# The kivy button behaviour does not switch images when using with `kv lang`

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

## **Goal**:

- To make an Image widget that works as a button.

---

### **Expected Result**:

- The Image button must switch the images accordingly.
- The Image button switches images correctly when using with Python directly but not with `.kv` file which causes the below problem.

---

### **Actual Result**:

- The `.kv` file only shows the image. The images doesn't get switched even when the `on_press` and `on_release` events dispatches.

---

The **main.py**:

```py
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_file('test1.kv')


class Test(FloatLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

---

And the **main_menu.kv:**

```
<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>

<Test>:
    FloatLayout:
        ImageButton:
            source: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_off'
            on_press:
                source: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_on'
            on_release:
                source: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_off'
```

---

#### The codes which are given above are the most minimal amount of code to reproduce the error!

---

### Thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the code below works.

```py
<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>

<MainMenu>:
    FloatLayout:
        ImageButton:
            source: "C:\\Users\\kanna\\Pictures\\OpenCity-Main_Menu\\PNG\\Build-Icon.png"
            on_press:
                self.source = "C:\\Users\\kanna\\Pictures\\OpenCity-Main_Menu\\PNG\\Build-Icon_Click.png"
            on_release:
                self.source = "C:\\Users\\kanna\\Pictures\\OpenCity-Main_Menu\\PNG\\Build-Icon.png"
```

The main problem was that on the right side of `on_` events like `on_press`, `on_release`, etc. the syntax must be like Python not like kvLang.
So, your `source: "c:/ bla-bla.."` must be `source = "c:/ bla-bla.."`

---

**The code has been updated.. again**

Comment: sir but i need a Image button widget variable
I have 10 Image buttons so How can i make it variable?

Comment: I can't able to click it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208315/discussion-between-sairam-kumar-and-noembryo).